# Can Firefox save download directory with more granularity than one directory per web site?

Tags: firefox

The `about.config` setting `browser.download.lastDir` allows Firefox to save a download folder for a site.
For `somewebsite.com`, there is a single download directory saved.

However for many sites (such as drive.google.com, box.com, dropbox etc) the site has an internal file system and organization. The site's structure needs to be reflected in the download path, otherwise it is necessary to navigate to a different local directory with each download.

How can Firefox be configured so that downloads from `somewebsite.com/abcd` default to a specific download directory, separate from the download directory saved for `somewebsite.com/defg`?

Comment: this appears to be an X-Y problem ... you are asking for help with a solution to an un-named problem even if the solution may be misguided ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is dealing with storage sites like dropbox, drive, etc. They are more like a file system than a web site.  For each downloaded file there are multiple manual steps involved in the file download process to select the Firefox Action/Save, and then navigating to the proper directory to save to (which is different every time because only one is saved for the whole site).  I can drag a file from the desktop to Firefox and it uploads, why can't I drag a link from Firefox to the desktop and have it download to the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

No, Firefox does not have a feature like this.

URL path (the path inside the web server after domain name) is not part of the domain name, and also it is not known by the resolver when deciding which DNS servers to use, and it is also not known by the DNS server when deciding what DNS records to return. So the URL path keeps unknown (and also unnecessary) in the whole DNS process. Only web server after TLS handshake knows it.

So this issue is a hard nut to crack.

Comment: I understand the path is not part of the domain name. But Firefox has the full domain+path in the address bar, history, elsewhere. I was thinking the browser's database current relation from domain to local directory could be extended to a relation including domain+path to local directory.